# Pipenv ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, django, pipenv

Searching for solution:

1. `pipenv install django`
2. `pipenv shell`
3. `django-admin startproject test .`
4. `python manage.py runserver`

Result:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'`

It is working with:

`pipenv run python manage.py runserver`

But it worked before without `pipenv run`

What's the case? Already reinstalled pipenv, cleared --lock, removed virtualenvs from `.local` folder, still same error when running `python manage.py runserver` inside project.

Answer (score 3):

Found solution.. I updated python yesterday so my alias was wrong need to realias it again. btw. to all having same problem `python3 manage.py runserver` solved my issue.